# Can't Get Bootstrap Navs to Display Correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the framework of a previous website I built as part of an assignment to build an actual website. However, when I copy all the code over, my navs do not look the same as they did when I did my assignment.

Here is the code, and you can view a live example of it at 192.241.215.180

The navigations are supposed to be "pills" and they are supposed to go across, not stack up.

```
<head>

    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

                <title>C$50 Finance: Portfolio</title>

    <script src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/scripts.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div id="top">
            <a href="/"><img alt="C$50 Finance" src="/img/logo.gif"/></a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar nav-pills" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/buy.php">Buy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/sell.php">Sell</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/quote.php">Quote</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/history.php">History</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/changepassword.php">Change Password</a><li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="middle">
        </div>

        <div id="bottom">
            Copyright &#169; John Harvard
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: change this   <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> to   <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-pills"> and see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a couple issues. First, your markup is incorrect, if you want pills, you need to use nav-pills class for the `<ul>` element, like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
```

While this should be enough, this alone won't do anything, because you have a bad CSS file and a bad JQuery file. I don't know how you managed to do that, but that's what you got. So, instead of using your files, try using the CDN versions, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

and

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

test them and see how they work out for you, but I'm sure this will fix your issues

Comment: Thank you! Not sure how I messed them up either, but it worked. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use `<ul class="nav nav-pills">`

FULL HTML:

```
<div class="container">

            <div id="top">
                <a href="/">
                    <img alt="C$50 Finance" src="/img/logo.gif" /></a>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar nav-pills" role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <div class="container">
                           <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                            <li class="active"><a href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/buy.php">Buy</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/sell.php">Sell</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/quote.php">Quote</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/history.php">History</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/changepassword.php">Change Password</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         <div id="middle">
            </div>

            <div id="bottom">
                Copyright &#169; John Harvard
            </div>

        </div>
```

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/ywlqFEZsOI)

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your version of Bootstrap.  Using this worked for me:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

there are some problem in your bootstrap.min.css

you can use this links

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

after these changes this will fix your issues